# How to change view on button click in iPhone without navigation?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am new to xCode. My project is based on viewbased application. For example, mainview consists of two buttons I named as button1 and button2.

If I click button2, it should appear a new view area in the same main view without navigation. Assume Now the two views are visible at same time. when i click the mainview, the secondary view should be disappear or hide. How it is possible to do this? plssss suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to define an IBAction on the buttons

the first action do stomething like

```
[myViewPopUp setHidden:NO];
[myviewPopUp setAlpha:1.f];
```

the second action sth like

```
[myViewPopUp setHidden:YES];
[myviewPopUp setAlpha:0.f];
```

or you can create a modal segue, on click 1st action

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: SEGUENAME sender:self];
```

and the second button :

```
[ViewPOPUp dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on an iPad app, you can do a modal view, which is just a window that can be any size.  You can also make one button on the first view that pushes a new view onto the navigation controller, and a button on the second that dismisses and pops the view controller from the navigation controller. I'll try to find some samples to share.